# I am hosting django project on hostinger using vps

Tags: python, django

I am trying to host my Django project on hostinger, I am using gunicorn to connect to vps and Nginx as the web  server

I correctly configured Nginx and gunicorn , everything is working without logs,But my site is not showing in the IP adress.

Comment: Did you add your server `ip address` to your nginx configuration file? it should be `server_name` in `server` block